# How to add icon for a opened folder in PyQt5 QFileIconProvider

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I know to add icon for a normal folder which is not opened but
how to add an icon for an opened folder

here is my current code

```
class FileIconProvider(QFileIconProvider):
    def icon(self, parameter):
  
        if isinstance(parameter, QFileInfo):
            info = parameter
            if info.isDir():
                #if it is folder then
                return QIcon("icons/folder.svg")
                #but how to check whether the folder is opened and give icon for it? 
        return super(FileIconProvider, self).icon(parameter)
```

Comment: Is that supposed to work with QFileSystemModel and QTreeView?

Comment: @musicamante Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A QTreeView sets the style option of the item to `State_Open` whenever the index is expanded, and the delegate uses that to select the proper icon *state*.

The solution is to add a new file to the existing icon with that state:

```
class FileIconProvider(QFileIconProvider):
    def icon(self, parameter):
        if isinstance(parameter, QFileInfo):
            if parameter.isDir():
                icon = QIcon("icons/folder.svg")
                icon.addFile("icons/folder-open.svg", state=icon.On)
                return icon
        return super().icon(parameter)
```

Note that, while this usually works anywhere, there is no absolute guarantee that the current style or delegate respects that, and in case it doesn't work you need to set a custom delegate and change the option icon in the `initStyleOption()`.